# WCF Services using same entity model class but exposes different in client

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, class, entity

I am new to WCF Services and can't get rid of this problem. For the next version of our web application I want to make use of WCF as webservice. Currently I am stuck with this problem:

To try WCF out I made 2 services: EmployeeService and AuthenticationService. I also made a datacontract **Employee**.

In AuthenticationService I use EmployeeService to get the logged **Employee**

Now in my client (ASP MVC Web) I add both Services as I need them both. But then when I try to use the object **Employee** I get the error :

Employee' is an ambiguous reference between 'IWA.Portal.AuthenticationService.Employee' and 'IWA.Portal.EmployeeService.Employee

The reason I want to make multiple services is to group them functionally. Example: Everything regarding employees will be under EmployeeService and everything regarding job will be under JobService.

How can I fix this or how should I structure my webservice?

**Currently my webservice solution consists of :**

- Project.DataContracts (Entities)
- Project.ServiceContracts (Interfaces)
- Project.Services (Services,    NHibernate & Castle Windsor)

Any help is much appreciated! Thx

**AuthenticationService**

```
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;

    public AuthenticationService(IEmployeeService employeeService)
    {
        _employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    public Employee Authenticate()
    {
        var employee = _employeeService.Get(1);

        return employee;
    }
}
```

**Code in my client (Controller)**

```
    readonly EmployeeServiceClient _employeeService = new EmployeeServiceClient();
    readonly AuthenticationServiceClient _authenticationService = new AuthenticationServiceClient();

    Employee authedEmployee = _authenticationService.Authenticate();
    Employee test = _employeeService.Get(827);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your namespaces are clashing and to fix it you will need to use full names in your code when referring to a class so instead of just Employee use

```
AuthenticationService.Employee auth_emp = new AuthenticationService.Employee();
```

and

```
EmployeeService.Employee es_emp = new EmployeeService.Employee();
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: This will fix my error indeed but the object does not have the same meaning if I do this.

Comment: In this case you should Have only one Employee class defined in your project and use it in both namespaces. You can pass an object from one namespace to another using dependency injection. Good start for you would be to read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection

Comment: I only have 1 employee class defined in my Project.DataContracts. I don't understand how DI can fix this. I am using DI to pass EmployeeService to my AuthenticationService .

Comment: Can you post part of the code which generates the problem?

Comment: So, why do you have two methods to return employee?

Comment: Well this is just a code example but should I not be able to use the same entities in multiple services? This will happen for sure when I transfer all my code to the webservice.

Comment: Yes, you can use same object in different namespaces, but best way to achieve it is DI. You need somebody to review your approach.

Comment: I don't see how I can fix this with DI. However If I would place everything in one service then I would have no problem but then I lose my grouping.